# Изменение строки по условию ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер, сравнение

В регистре EBX хранится адрес, в котором хранится строка(String1).
Мне нужно сравнить первые четыре символа строки String1 со String2.
Если они равны, то изменить строку на String3.
Ассемблер изучаю недавно.
Буду очень благодарен, если поможете разобраться

Comment: Значит, сначала вам понадобятся инструкции сравнения и изменения регистра (содержащего адрес).

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста. Не могу найти

Comment: ОК, [поищу за Вас](http://natalia.appmat.ru/c&c++/assembler.html)

Comment: Я могу использовать команду cmp для сравнения регистра содержащего адрес со строкой?

Answer (score 0):

Четыре первых символа можно сравнить за одну операцию, если использовать указатели на строки как указатели на `dword`:

```
  mov eax, dword ptr[String2] ;загружаем 4 байта по указателю String2
  cmp eax, dword ptr[ebx] ;сравниваем с 4 байтами по указателю из ebx
  jne not_equal

  mov esi, String3 ;копирование String3 в String1
  mov edi, ebx
copy: lodsb
  stosb
  test al, al ;предполагается, что строки null-терминированные
  jnz copy

not_equal:
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а какое командой внести данные по указателю? Одна строка у меня уже есть в памяти. Вторую нужно туда добавить.

Comment: Можно ли сравнить так cmp eax, 73747231(4 байта строки) ?

Comment: @minaevmaksimik, а почему вдруг в памяти оказалась только одна из строк, где остальные? Что имеется в виду под словами "вторую нужно туда добавить"? Её нужно ввести с клавиатуры, прочитать из файла или откуда она должна взяться?

Comment: Вторую строку я должен добавить в память сам. Как мне это сделать?Я могу добавить строку в виде байт командой?

Comment: Одной командой - нет. Ответ на вопрос "как мне это сделать?" зависит от ответа на заданный выше вопрос: "откуда она (строка) должна взяться?".